# Indirect expansion returns variable name instead of value

Tags: linux, bash, variables, variable-names, indirection

I am trying to set up some variables using indirect expansion.  According to the documentation I've read, the set up should be simple:

```
var1=qa
qa_num=12345
varname="${var1}_ci"

echo ${!varname}
```

I should be getting "12345".  Instead, the output is "varname".  If I remove the exclamation point, I end up with "qa_ci", not "12345"

This should be a relatively simple solution, so I'm not sure what I'm missing, if anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code defines `qa_num`, but the `varname` assignment references `qa_ci`.  As a result, your `echo` was expanding nonexistent `qa_ci`, giving empty results.  Changing the `varname` assignment fixes the problem on my system.

Example: `foo.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=qa
qa_num=12345
varname="${var1}_num"     # <=== not _ci

echo "${!varname}"        # I also added "" here as a general good practice
```

Output:

```
$ bash foo.sh
12345
```

Comment: This worked, though I should mention that the typo only existed on this question, not the actual code.  On that note, I was trying these lines in the linux console and they did not work.  Only when I created an actual script with it.  Why does that make a difference?

Comment: @SVill I'm not sure.  On my Cygwin bash, the four lines of `foo.sh`, run one at a time in the console, result in `12345`, as they should.  However, more complicated scripts (e.g., that rely on `shopt` settings) sometimes behave differently in the shell.  I'd suggest asking a new question with a minimal, testable example of the difference in behaviour.  Good luck!